# Template dropdown or button

Tags: templates

Is ther a way to add a Dropdown or a button to the toolbar that when selected or clicked insert a template collected from a txt file.

Dropdown for if i have multiply templates in a directory.
a button if i only got one file in that Dir.

```
<script>
    var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
        theme: 'snow'
    });

    // Function to handle the custom button click
    function handleCustomButtonClick() {
        // Load the text file content from 'files/template.txt'
        fetch('files/template.txt')
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(text => {
                quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(quill.getSelection().index, text);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error loading text file:', error);
            });
    }

    // Create a custom button and add it to the Quill toolbar
    var customButton = document.createElement('button');
    customButton.textContent = 'Insert Text';
    customButton.addEventListener('click', handleCustomButtonClick);
    quill.getModule('toolbar').container.appendChild(customButton);

    // Update the hidden input field with Quill content
    var form = document.querySelector('form');
    form.onsubmit = function() {
        var contentInput = document.querySelector('#content');
        contentInput.value = quill.root.innerHTML;
    };
</script>
```

it did not do the job, and the "Button" was hovering over the other tools